# What is the proper diagram to describe an event subscriber final graph?

Tags: microservices, documentation, diagrams, event, flow

I'm working on a microservice application and I need to describe the complete execution graph of a specific event being published, where each node in the graph is a specific microservice subscription to this first event.

This diagram should be able to describe new events that are eventually published in response of this first event as well (the one that generates the whole execution graph).

Which diagrams are used to describe this kind of flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use an [UML sequence diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram). But with a long chain you might end with an unreadable diagram.

The [UML communication diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-communication-diagram/) would therefore offer a more compact and convenient overview, with the different services involved, their links and chronologically numbered messages exchanged labeled with the different events produced/consumed.